# intent to start activity does not work

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start my GameOverActivity trough a Intent, but my game chrashs when the conditions are true:

In my GameView class:

```
//conditions (they work, i tested it)
theGameActivity.onGameOver();
```

in my GameActivity:

```
public void onGameOver() {
        Intent theNextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameOverActivity.class);
        startActivity(theNextIntent);
        this.finish();
    }
```

Everytime the GameOverActivity should start, my game crashes...

Comment: Provide crash logs please. And make sure the activity is defined in AndroidManifest.

Comment: post the logcat, the problem could be in GameOverActivity.java, also..if you can use this.finish, then you can also pass "this" in Intent instead of getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1):

rather do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

You can just copy and paste it and it should be fine. You should also make sure that your activity is declared in your manifest file.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work: Replaced my  with your code and added the activity in the manifest (forgot it :( )

Comment: @user3447262 I know this is old. With Android studio you don't need to add activities to the manifest. And gradle is a blessing